# javascript drive api gapi client request with variable

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I need to search for a folder in Google Drive, through a html page with javascript.
I have a javascript function that works:

```
 function listFiles() {

        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            q:  " mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='SearchFolder' ",
            pageSize: 10,
            fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"

        });

        request.execute(function (resp) {
            console.log('Files:');
            var files = resp.files;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {

                    var file = files[0];
                    console.log(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');

            } else {
                console.log('No files found.');
            }
        });
```

Instead of that string at the q parameter, i tried to use something like this:

```
  var folderSearch= 'TypeNameHere';
     var string =JSON.stringify('mimeType = '+"'"+'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'+ "'"+' and name='+"'"+folderSearch+ "'" );


 var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                q:  string,
                pageSize: 10,
                fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"         });
```

But it doesn't work. How can I pass a variable in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea - just don't use `JSON.stringify`. That's for serialising (converting) an object to a string, but it's already a string.

Change the string to this...

```
var string = " mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='" + folderSearch + "' ";
```